# Use a Timer to increment a ProgressBar and show a count-down

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, progress-bar

I need some help in making a count-down Timer that also increments a ProgressBar.
I have a Button that generates a random time (expressed in minutes) that will increment a ProgressBar, to use as a form of *loader*.

When the ProgressBar increments its value, I would like to show, in a Label, the time remaining.

Here is my code:

```
int RandomNumber;
int MinutesElapsed;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    RandomNumber = random.Next(1, 121); // at (x, x) there is a limit from x to x+1
    MinutesElapsed = 0;
    QuestTimer1.Start(); // starts the timer
}

private void QuestTimer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MinutesElapsed++;
    double minutes = MinutesElapsed / 1.2;
    progressBar1.Value = (int)minutes;
}
```

Comment: FYI - Don't initialize a `new Random()` every time the button is clicked. Use a `static readonly Random = new Random();` field and use that as a random number generator.

Comment: So, what is the problem? Just add a textbox and update it with the remaining time?

Comment: @JonasH that is the problem I don't know how to write it :D

Comment: So, what research have you done? what solutions have you attempted? Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service, It is expected that more effort is made than "I want to do X please show me how".

Comment: @JonasH I tried to research the same "Time remaining" counter and I came across one code that actually had the label that I had and I just neded to remake the code to make it work. So I joinked it and pasted it and made some slight changes and from 8 errors it went down to 3. So I contacted my friends to help me out and I showed them the code and mine attemps on it. They said yes and no there should be more to it. I sent them the site where I've gotten it from. Now I tried to do it myself and came up with a solution. I will update the question and share the error while running the program :)

Comment: Post your question about reader.readlune again. I will tell you what to do

Answer (score 0):

A few notes that may be useful:
Your Button (you should give it a proper name) can be used to start/stop the Timer and generate a new random number, representing minutes, using a [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random) object (declared as a static Field - not so important here, but because of its internal functionality, it's more reliable this way).

The generated random value initializes a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan) object (`totalTime`) that store the total time, to keep as reference.
You can set a measure of time directly in the TimeSpan constructor: if the values - expressed in minutes here - overflows the normal measure (60 minutes in this case), the TimeSpan class computes the correct value (i.e., if you set the Minutes component to `90` in the constructor, the TimeSpan will be automatically compute 1 Hour and 30 minutes).

Another TimeSpan (`minutesElapsed`) will store the time elapsed.

The Timer's `Interval` is set to `1000ms`.
The ProgrssBar should keep its standard range of values: `(0 - 100)`.
You can see it as the percentage of completion. Each time the Timer ticks, we'll adapt the difference between the total time and the elapsed time, squeezing it in this range of values .

```
TimeSpan totalTime;
TimeSpan minutesElapsed;
static Random rnd = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    QuestTimer1.Stop();
    minutesElapsed = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    // 0 Hours, N Minutes, 0 Seconds
    totalTime = new TimeSpan(0, rnd.Next(1, 121), 0);

    lblTimeLeft.Text = totalTime.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    QuestTimer1.Start();
}
```

The Timer ticks - 1 second has passed - so increment the elapsed time by one second and calculate the difference between the total time and the current number of elapsed seconds.
TimeSpan objects support common operators to perform addition and subtraction and provide different properties to evaluate their value in Ticks, Milliseconds, Seconds etc.

Each second, a Label (here named `lblTimeLeft`) is updated, showing how many seconds are left (acts as a count-down), while the ProgressBar increments it's Value.

When `minutesElapsed >= totalTime`, the Timer is stopped.

```
private void QuestTimer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    minutesElapsed += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

    lblTimeLeft.Text = (totalTime - minutesElapsed).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    progressBar1.Value = (int)(minutesElapsed.TotalMinutes / totalTime.TotalMinutes * 100D);

    if (minutesElapsed.TotalMinutes >= totalTime.TotalMinutes) {
        QuestTimer1.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may seem counterintuitive, but when implementing a "timer," there is no need for an actual timer to keep the time. You certainly don't need to set a timer and increment a variable every second-- your system clock already does that! Your program just needs to know the start time, end time, and current time, and at any given moment, in can compute the progress % and the time remaining.

When you start the process, take note of the current time and store the target completion time.

```
DateTime _startTime;
DateTime _endTime;

private void StartTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _startTime = DateTime.Now;
    var duration = random.Next(1, 121); 
    _endTime = _startTime.AddSeconds(duration);
}
```

Then when you wish to know the time remaining or progress, compute them:

```
public int SecondsRemaining => (_endTime - DateTime.Now).TotalSeconds;

public double PercentComplete => ((double)(_endTime - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds) / (_endTime - _startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
```

You can call either of these properties at any time and they will always give you the percent complete and time remaining accurately. You don't need a separate timer at all!

However, you probably want to update the display every now and then. You need a timer for that, but it can run at any interval, and it's easy to write:

```
void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TimeRemainingLabel.Text = SecondsRemaining.ToString() + " seconds";
    this.ProgressBar.Value = (int)(PercentComplete * 100);
}
```